# Installation problem after broken installation of zoom

Tags: package-management

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package zoom needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try to

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-all zoom`

This will uninstall zoom ; then you'll have to install zoom.

*Replace amd64 by i386 for 32bit arch*

```
wget https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

[Zoom Guide](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux)